# Neural Network Type for Time Series Approximation

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, feed-forward

I am currently trying to decide which type of neural network I should choose to complete the following task:

First imagine the following problem setup:

We are looking at a 2D airfoil with a prescribed motion pattern (traverse as well as periodic rotational/flapping movement). This means the lift and drag produced by the foil will show some kind of harmonic behaviour related to the flapping movement of the foil.

The neural network should be capable of approximating the behaviour of the lift (or drag) of the foil over one period of flapping motion for airfoil geometries which differ from the training data in selected geometrical parameters.
Currently I could envision two approaches to solve this (it is mandatory to use some kind of neural network approach)

1) Use a standard feed-forward neural network with the output parameters being the lift / drag at discrete points of the flapping period. Depending on the complexity of the lift / drag curve many output parameters would be needed. Input parameters are geometrical parameters such as chord length / camber / ...

2) Use a recurrent neural network in order to capture the temporal progression. I am not sure if this is needed or meaningful but most time-series related problems are solved with RNNs.

I would be really grateful for any kind of suggestions regarding the problem!

Best Regards,

Bob

Comment: Why are you assuming a neural network is the right model for the problem?
Sounds like you should investigate simulation modeling further. Also, sharing the details of the inputs in terms of variables and class descriptions would help...

Comment: Usually I would also use other means to complete the task. Using a neural network is mandatory due to the assignment that was given. I am not totally sure about the input parameters yet; my question is rather aimed at finding out if it is possible to use a feed-forward network in order to obtain the time series of drag and lift over one period by specifying the output to be values of drag or lift at discrete points of the motion period

Comment: Try it and find out.